# Elegant way to remove orphan rows?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a lot of history entries that contain customer IDs.

There is a separate customer table. Occasionally some of the customer entries are removed.

Is there an easy way, without looping through each history entry, to drop all rows in the history table where the customer ID no longer exists because the customer row was deleted?

Comment: Do you want to do the delete each time a customer is deleted, or only periodically?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
delete from history_table where customer_id not in (select customer_id from customers)
```

did you mean something like this?

Comment: Its weakness is that it can't handle self-joins (eg parentid in table). It may also be slower than the proper join...but that maybe insignificant on small tables.

Answer (score 16):

```
DELETE h.* FROM history h
LEFT JOIN customer c ON h.customer_id = c.id
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

I'm typing this from the top of my head, but you get the idea hopefully.

[Delete syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: This is the proper solution.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
DELETE FROM history_table 
WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM customer);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use cascading with foreign keys to accomplish this.  In the following example, any time a row is deleted from A, or an A_ID in A is changed, this change will automatically be reflected in table B.  You can read more on foreign keys [in the MySql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

```
CREATE TABLE A(
   A_ID INT, 
   PRIMARY_KEY(A_ID)
) TYPE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE B(
   B_ID INT,
   A_ID INT,
   CONSTRAINT FK_B_A FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES A(A_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY_KEY(B_ID, A_ID)
) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: As customers are deleted and their history must be deleted either, so the best solution is this one. There's no point in deleting parent tables records without deleting it's childs too, so let the database handle this as @Ryan Gross said!

Comment: This is the best solution as it handles nested references and you don't need to write a second query to delete related records. Deleting the parent will be enough to delete the related history.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_HISTORY CH
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CUSTOMER C WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID = CH.CUSTOMER_ID)
```